# Distributions of ranks of random integer matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory

Fix numbers $m, n, k\in {\Bbb Z}_+$ and $r\in {\Bbb R}_+$.

What non-trivial estimates exist for the probability that a random $m\times n$ matrix, with integer entries and with all its rows of Euclidean norm less than or equal to $r$, will have rank $k$?

I'm particularly interested in results asymptotic in the variable $r$.  (I've worked out the coefficient for $m=n=2, k=1$, but my method doesn't seem to generalize.)

Comment: If you get no other data, look up Miodrag Zivkovic and classification of 0-1 matrices.  That and one other work (I think of his, but my memory is not fully cooperating right now) consider ranks for 0-1 matrices, and may give you something that you can use.  It will not directly address your question though.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.25

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is addressed in

MR1169034 (94e:11073) 
Katznelson, Yonatan R.(1-MSRI)
Integral matrices of fixed rank. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 120 (1994), no. 3, 667–675.

Comment: Thank you Igor for this reference!  I see that Katznelson actually treats a very closely related problem - he takes a disk in ${\Bbb R}^{m\times n}$ where I asked about a polydisk.  I haven't had enough time with the paper yet to judge whether that makes much difference.

Comment: It does not make any difference, the percentage of the matrices you want is the same, as long as the domain is reasonably regular (which the polydisk certainly is).